# substring with an array string - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, substring

I have an array:

```
var array = ["1|First", "2|Second", "3|Third"]
```

How I can cut off "1|", "2|", "3|"?
The result should look like this:

```
println(newarray) //["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use (assuming the strings will contain the "|" character):

```
let newarray = array.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|")[1] }
```

As @Grimxn pointed out, if you cannot assume that the "|" character will always be in the strings, use:

```
let newarray = array.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|").last! }
```

or

```
let newarray2 = array.map { $0.substringFromIndex(advance(find($0, "|")!, 1)) }
```

result2 could be a little bit faster, because it doesn't create an intermediate array from `componentsSeparatedByString`.

or if you want to modify the original array:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
    array[index] = array[index].substringFromIndex(advance(find(array[index], "|")!, 1))
}
```

Comment: Swift 1.2 syntax: `map(array) { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|")[1] }`
The answer is swift 2.0

Comment: actually, mine as well Swift 1.2

Comment: ops, my mistake. Swift 1.2 has `map()` as global function and array function as well

Comment: This solution will crash if the "|" doesn't exist. Try it with `var array = ["1|First", "2|Second", "3|Third", "Fourth"]`.

Consider changing the solution to `let newarray = array.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|").last! }`